# How do you make an array that has 1-3 int, instead of the default 0-3 int?

Tags: java

How do you make an array that has 1-3 int, instead of the default 0-3 int?
like

```
int[] anArray;
anArray = new int[3];
has numbers 0-3 I want index starting at 1
```

Comment: You want your index to start at `1`?

Comment: When you create an array, it has no values defined in it. You are talking about index.

Comment: You can go to matlab!

Comment: If I understand your question, you'd like to start the array at the position `1`, right?

Comment: Get used to the language for the sake of your peers.

Comment: Unfortunately, Java's array handling is rather primitive. You are stuck with 0-based if you use an actual array. You could construct your own data structure with 1-based indexing, but that might confuse some Java programmers who are unfamiliar with languages like Fortran that have more flexible arrays.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan - but not old versions of Fortran.

Comment: @StephenC True, for some definitions of "old".

Comment: I learned it as Fortran IV ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You make an array of four elements, and then never use the '0' element.

Sorry, but you can't change the language.

Answer (score 1):

The index starts at 0. You'll just need to set The variable different in your loops if it helps readability

Instead of for I=0; i

You'd use

For I= 1; I

Would recommend you get use to indexing from zero though.

Apologies for typos. Using phone

Answer (score 0):

You don't, arrays in Java start their indices at 0.

And `new int[3]` does not have numbers 0-3, it has indices 0-2.

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't allow this.  In most programming languages, array indexes start from zero.  And in the cases where they start from one, you can't change the lower bound.

The only main-stream<sup>1</sup> language I can think of where you could specify both the lower and upper bounds of an array is Ada.  (And recent versions of Fortran too ...)

---

<sup>1 ... and calling Ada mainstream these days is "a stretch".</sup>

Comment: In the generics type handling, Scala allows upper and lower bounds.  It isn't quite the same as an indexing range, but it is one upper-and-lower bound example to consider.